# Free viewer for Excel files other than OpenOffice

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, ms-office

Other than OpenOffice, can you suggest a light free viewer for Excel files?

Answer (score 12):

Isn't [Quick Look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look) enough?

You could also try to upload them on [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com).

Comment: +1 for QuickLook. You can't do any editing within QuickLook, mind you, but simply for viewing you can't get any more lightweight than that.

Comment: +1 here as well as I don't even have Office on my Mac and I can still view Office documents, and I just use OpenOffice if I ever have to get content out of them.

Comment: +1 Quicklook is really useful when you just want to read a Microsoft Office file.

Comment: I'm aware of QuickLook and it is great, however the view disappears when you edit another document. Moreover, you cannot copy and paste text from the view.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Look can be set to allow copying of text.  Launch Terminal and type the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool true
```

Then restart the Finder with the following command:

```
killall Finder
```

After selecting use the keyboard <kbd>⌘+C</kbd> to copy.

Read more at [Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/268138/enable-copying-text-quick-look-os-x-tips/#zQYtZBFwYM0qbpoz.99)

#### EDIT

Selecting text seems to be disabled in OS X 10.11.  But this Terminal hack works in many versions prior to 10.11.

Comment: Could we make this answer more brief?

Comment: Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I myself use OS X's [Quick Look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look). I think it's good enough.

Just select your xls (or xlsx) file and do one of the following:

- press <kbd>Space</kbd>
- press <kbd>⌘ Y</kbd>
- right click and choose Quick Look

and the file will be viewable in a separate window. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> again to close.

Quick Look can also be opened in full screen by pressing <kbd>⌥ Space</kbd> or  <kbd>⌥ ⌘ Y</kbd> in the Finder. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit full screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Numbers](https://www.apple.com/numbers/) can be used to view Excel spreadsheet files. Numbers is available for macOS, iOS and web. Numbers which was previously a paid app is now available free of cost. Numbers web app can be used on compatible browsers even on a Windows and Linux computer.

Comment: How well does Numbers cover Excel features and file types?

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is just to provide an update as of March 2016**

Microsoft Office Online will allow you to not just view, but create, edit, and save Excel documents without having the software installed.

[image]

For a complete list of features available for [Excel Online, check out the page on support.office.com page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Basic-tasks-in-Excel-Online-0DCAC23B-8430-4289-87A5-F2C97BDB49E1)